# Objective C: "Property implementation must have its declaration in interface"

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

//RootViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UITextField *login_uname;
    IBOutlet UITextField *login_pword;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *login_thinger;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *logo;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *login_remember;

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
}




-(IBAction) login_submitClick:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) doneEditing:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) clearPword:(id)sender;
-(void) showSignUp:(id)sender;

-(void)doLogout:(id)sender;

//for file handling:
-(NSString *)documentsPath;
-(NSString *)readFromFile:(NSString *)filePath;
-(void) writeToFile:(NSString *)text withFileName:(NSString *) filePath;

@end
```

//RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
//#import "Main.h"
//#import "SignUp.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"
#import "CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h"
#import "Details.h"
//#import "signUpSMS.h"
#import "JSON.h"

@implementation PrestoCab3ViewController
@synthesize login_uname;   //this line throws the error in the title

...
```

I'm using XCode 4.1 and was wondering if someone could please help me get to the bottom of this error. I'm very new to XCode.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: The @synthesize should have an equivalent property declarations.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to declare the property with @property in your interface.

```
@property( nonatomic, retain ) IBOutlet UITextField * login_uname;
```

Here, non-atomic is used because it's an IBOutlet.
Also note the property has the retain modifier, meaning you are responsible to release the object when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: If you find you are still getting this message but have an @property in your interface then try doing a Product > Clean.