# “Property implementation must have its declaration in interface” error in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, properties, getter-setter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C: “Property implementation must have its declaration in interface”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420100/objective-c-property-implementation-must-have-its-declaration-in-interface)

I have a declared a object of a viewController globally in another viewController.

**I am pretty sure that**

1- i have imported the necessary viewController class

2 - i have witten the @property(nonatomic, retain) for that object in .h file

3 - i have synthesized the same object .m file

But still i am getting the error saying that **“Property implementation must have its declaration in interface”**.   What am i doing wrong here.... i'v been scratching my head on this issue....

**.h file**

```
#import "viewController1.h"

@interface viewController2 :UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{        
    viewController2 *vc2;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)viewController2 *vc2;

-(void)someMethod;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "viewController2.h"

@implementation viewController2

@synthesize vc2;

@end
```

Comment: Maybe show us some code / a screenshot?

Comment: Could you post the header for the class the property is declared in? We'll be able to help if we can see some code.

Comment: Have you declared the variable in the interface before setting the property?

Comment: YEah... there is some explanation needed in order to answer your question... just one thing... there is no such thing as a global variable in Obj-C all variables are private by definition.

Comment: @Marsson Objective-C is a superset of ANSI C, so global variables do exist. Your statement "in Obj-C all variables are private by definition" is more bewildering though. Did you mean all *instance variables*? Instance variables are **protected** by default, not private, and their visibility can be modified.

Comment: hi guys, please refer my updated question above... i have updated the question and included some code snippets...

Answer (score 1):

1. Clean your project
2. Declare the property like so : `@property(readwrite,retain)viewController2 *vc2;`.

Answer (score 0):

use like this (use @class directive)

```
 @class YourClassName
 @interface Second : UIViewController
{

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) YourClassName *obj;
```

and synthesize it in .m file.

Comment: hi ishu.. like i mentioned in my question, i have done exactly the same thing but still got the error... :(

Comment: @A for Alpha, you are importing the file, try the class directive as above mentioned